# Quartz.Net Cron trigger to repeat task each day for a duration of time

Tags: quartz.net

I am trying to create a trigger that:

Run a job on chosen days of week( say Mon, Wed, Thu) and repeat this job for X hours or Minutes for a duration of Y Minutes on each of these days.

I have a cron trigger that fires correctly on the specified days but I am not able to get the repeat interval working.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

If the question is about "how to create a trigger that fires only at some given days, repeatedly during X hours/minutes, and with an interval of Y minutes", then it's not possible with Quartz.NET 1.0.

However, if you are willing to use Quartz.NET 2.0 (currently in beta 2), you can do it easily by using calendars and DailyTimeIntervalSchedule:

```
        WeeklyCalendar cal = new WeeklyCalendar();
        cal.SetDayExcluded(DayOfWeek.Monday, true);
        sched.AddCalendar("excludedDays", cal, false, false);

        var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("test", "group")
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(
                x => x.StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(14, 0))
                         .EndingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(15, 0))
                         .WithIntervalInSeconds(5))
            .ModifiedByCalendar("excludedDays")
            .Build();
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare job duration but you can easily time the duration from within the job.

Anyway, the cron expression which will schedule the job based on your specification is:

```
35 30 1/2 ? * MON,WED,THU *
```

`1/2` means that the job will run every 2 hours starting from 1:30:35 AM.

You can play with cron expressions on [this useful website.](http://java.dzone.com/announcements/wwwcronmakercom-helper-web) It uses the original Java version of Quartz to create and validate the expressions, however, the .net version is a port of the Java one, so the results should be valid for quartz.net.